# Cart arrays and sessions

Tags: php, arrays, session

Okay, I'm having problems with this.  I'm trying to add product to cart the product as options colour and so, but I just can't seem to get it right.  If I just hit "Add to Cart", it will and count each time, but if I change the colour, then it starts to go wrong.  Help, guys and girls!  Been working on this for some time.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                       $id = $_POST['id'];
                       $sleeve = $_POST['sleeve'];
                       $colour = $_POST['colour'];
                       $size = $_POST['size'];
                       $action = $_POST['action'];
                       $quantity = 1;
                       }
                       if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){ 
                             $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array($id, $colour, $size, $quantity);      
                       }
                          else{
                                if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){ // if the session as already been set then..
                                       while(list($key, $value) = each($_SESSION['cart'])){ // while loop to chech to content of the session..
                                              if($value[0] == $id && $value[1] == $colour && $value[2] == $size){ // checking to see if the session content is the same..
                                                    $quantity = $value[3] +=1;
                                                    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array($id, $colour, $size, $quantity); // if it is the same then add this..
                                                 }// if is ==
                                                    else{
                                                         $quantity +=1;
                                                         $_SESSION['cart'][$id][] = array($id, $colour, $size, $quantity); // is session is not the same do this..
                                                        }//else if it is not ==

                                             }// while
                                       }// if isset
                               }// else isset session
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are checking every item in cart against one item, if current item will match at first iteration then shouldn't it go out of loop and set flag that item is present so after loop, increment that items quantity otherwise after loop add another instance.

But still the way you are adding the product's other instance having different color will not work next time when you will add another instance of product and will check via your if portion.

Here you are inserting item against $id key:

```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){ 
                         $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array($id, $colour, $size, $quantity);      
                   }
```

While in else portion when item id is same but different attributes you are adding product to another child array of cart:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$id][] = array($id, $colour, $size, $quantity); // is session is not the same do this..
```

So you should either add every product/item as :

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$id][] = array($id, $colour, $size, $quantity);
```

in both cases either first variation of product or other variation.

However if your price differ from variation by variation then use different product instance id for every item's every variation.

If I am unclear at any point then please ask, also tell if I haven't understood your problem.